# Can we say "expertise knowledge"? A phrase with two synonyms

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request, adjectives, nouns

As I checked the google, expertise is a noun and means "expert skill or knowledge in a particular field".

I made the following sentence:

> .. doesn’t require expertise knowledge of HTML.

As I checked google for the phrase "require expertise knowledge", it found 99,100 cases; However in some of them knowledge came after a comma after expertise like:

> Knowledge worker's are employees who require expertise, knowledge, or information from others to perform their jobs effectively

Can I rely on these results and employ this phrase?

Can the noun "expertise" which is a synonym of "knowledge" come before it to make a phrase?

Comment: Expert knowledge

Comment: @pazzo I myself found this phrase too "... doesn’t require expertise in HTML"

Comment: @Ahmad, take a look at my answer for this.  In short: 'doesn't require experise in HTML' means 'doesn't require being a HTML expert' or 'doesn't require expert knowledge of HTML'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Expertise knowledge' is not correct, I would use 'expert knowledge' or 'expertise' instead of 'expertise knowledge'

> Knowledge worker's are employees who require expertise, knowledge, or
> information from others to perform their jobs effectively

Expertise is mostly synonymous with 'expert knowledge'.  In the phrase 'expert knowledge', 'expert' is used as an **adjective** to describe the type/level of 'knowledge'.  The word 'expert' can also be used as a noun to describe a person who has 'expertise' or 'expert knowledge'.

A person **is** an expert
A person **has** expertise

In regards to your specific sentence:

> .. doesn’t require **expert knowledge** of HTML.
>
> .. doesn't require **expertise** in HTML

Comment: Thank you, can we conclude if we found a 'noun' it can't become before another noun? and it must be only adjective? if no, which nouns usually come together?

Comment: You can get nouns before nouns in sentences but usually they are used to help you describe something more specifically than if you had only used one noun.  These are called **compound nouns**.  For example if I said: 'he is a player', you would not know what kind of player he was/what he played. If I said 'he is a piano player', you have more information. These can be found hyphenated e.g. 'noun-noun' or with a space 'noun noun' or even with no space e.g. 'nounnoun'.  More details + more examples can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Types_of_compound_nouns

Comment: @Ahmad You can say *expertise knowledge*, but that is not how native speakers would say it. Sometimes there is no rule to go by, only how native users put the words together.

Comment: @Ahmad: nouns can modify nouns.   *tree knowledge* would be knowledge of trees. So *expertise knowledge* would be knowledge of expertise, which could make sense in only a very strained context, knowing which person in an organization is expert in which subject, for example.

Comment: @TRomano, I hadn't considered that one could have knowledge of expertise when writing this!

Comment: @amblina: Your answer was correct and I gave it a +1. I was just trying to explain to Ahmad how unlikely *expertise knowledge* would be; it is only  possible given a highly unusual context, and even then it would sound odd to 999 people out of 1000.